# Ubuntu 14.04 wireless network setup

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, kvm-virtualization, network-bridge

I am trying to setup *kvm* on my laptop. These are the steps I have done so far.

1. Uninstalled existing windows7 and installed Ubuntu 14.04 on the
   laptop.
2. I have a network which provides me wireless connections. Now, I am
   able to connect to the network using the wifi conncection.
3. I am trying to add the wireless information into my `/etc/network/interfaces` file as below.

   ```
   auto wlan0
   iface wlan0 inet dhcp
   ```

   (In this step, I even tried specifying WPA SSID and WPA Key in the configuration file. But I couldn't connect to the network).
4. However, I am not able to connect to the network if I edit the
   `/etc/network/interfaces` file. If I run `iwconfig` *wlan0* is the wireless interface name I get which is why I am adding *wlan0* in my `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

What am I doing wrong? My end goal is to setup a *kvm* bridge so that I could install another OS on the bare metal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/245970/334241), I was able to figure out that the name server was not set properly in my configuration file and after setting it, I could make it run.

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.1.9
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
wpa-ssid my_ssid
wpa-psk my_ssid_password

dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
dns-search lan
dns-domain lan
```